# multiple data validations excel macros

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I need to consolidate the following two data validations into one condition

[Validation formuala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb0X1.png)
Here is the full formula from the image:

((86400*((E5-D5)+(E6-D6)+(E7-D7)+(E8-D8)+(E9-D9)+(E10-D10)+(E11-D11)))/3600)+(7.5*SUM(G5:G11))<=37.50

[Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG3bu.jpg)

I assumed I needed VBA to do this, please advise if at all possible

Thanks

Comment: you didnt provide any of your own attempts. That being said your data validation would more likely be date format translations (take their input and convert it to your own) and a basic IF statement that would check values of (hours) and then execution an action based on that condition. This should get you started to be able to try it for yourself first.

Comment: You can do almost exactly everything you need using the [data validation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9) feature in Excel - no need for VBA.

Comment: @Vegard please elaborate. how can i write a formula to enforce 24hr time format I can do each of the conditions individually but not simultaneously which is why i felt i needed to use VBA. fairly clueless though- Thank again

Comment: From the data validation menu, choose "Allow: Timestamp", then add numberformat for 24h timestamps for those cells. If a valid timestamp is entered, it will display as 24h regardless.

Comment: @DougCoats  I have reworded my issue hopefully this is easier to understand now - thanks

Comment: @Vegard There is no option to allow time stamp only time

Comment: @Vegard but I need a custom data validation. this is my issue!

Comment: Why? If you just want 24H format, you can do that with cell formatting and the validation as described. What condition do you need enforced that is not covered by this?

Comment: @Vegard because I'm using the 24hr format for a start and end time to calculate hours worked and this cannot exceed 37.5

Comment: Having glanced at the previous screenshot you posted, that does not seem to pose a problem. You can use formulas to validate the 37.5hr rule. I'll post an answer to show you the formula setup.

Comment: @Vegard Thank you very much

Comment: Actually, can you post the first screenshot again? The one where we can see how the workbook looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use [data validation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9) to take care of the timestamps.

To enforce the condition "put any number of worked time in excess of 37,5 hrs into overtime", you can use two formulas to solve this.

Assuming a workbook looking roughly like this:

```
    A          B        C
1  Days       Hours    Hours
2  Monday     8        8
3  Tuesday    8        6
4  Wednesday  8        7
5  Thursday   8        5
6  Friday     8        3
7
8  Regular
9  Overtime
10 Sum hrs
```

In cells B8 and C8, use this formula (enter it in to B8 and copy it to C8):
`=IF(SUM(B$2:B$6) > 37,5; 37,5; SUM(B$2:B$6))`

In cells B9 and C9, use this formula (enter it in to B9 and copy it to C9):
`=IF(SUM(B$2:B$6) > 37,5; SUM(B$2:B$6) - 37,5; 0)`

The workbook from above will then look like this:

```
    A          B        C
1  Days       Hours    Hours
2  Monday     8        8
3  Tuesday    8        6
4  Wednesday  8        7
5  Thursday   8        5
6  Friday     8        3
7
8  Regular    37,5     29
9  Overtime   2,5      0
10 Sum hrs    40       29
```

This can be adapted (with some changes to the formulae) to work with a scenario where you put "Started work" in one column and "Ended work" in another column. If you show me how your workbook looks, I can see about making such a change for you.